# Difference between object destructuring and and destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

For example if I have an object like this:

```
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }
let { a, b } = obj;
console.log(a, b); // output 1, 2
```

But if a and b are initialized, like this:

```
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let a = 3, b = 4;
{ a, b } = obj;
console.log(a, b); // error
```

What is the difference between them, why the second output an error?

Answer (score 7):

You need parentheses around the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) do distinguish destructuring from a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) where an assignment to it is not possible.

[Assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration):

> The round braces `( ... )` around the assignment statement is required syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> **NOTE: Your `( ... )` expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.**

```js
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let a = 3, b = 4;

({ a, b } = obj);
console.log(a, b); // 1, 2
```

Comment: But why should do like this, maybe I don't understand block statement

Comment: the [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) is the structure which follows an `for` statement, for example. please have a look to the link for more information.

Comment: Why surrounded with parentheses the assignment becomes valid, and why add var before it also becomes valid.

Comment: it converts the part inside to an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions). and a block statement is not an expression.